# The route of data transferred via SSH seems strange

Tags: networking, ssh, routing

What I noticed is that the packets transferred via SSH go to the router first and then the router transfers them to the destination host.

But why? Why not just transfer data directly by the MAC address between the two hosts?

I've captured some packets via Wireshark as an example:

[image: Source host packet captured]
[image: Destination host packet captured]

**Note**: `IETF-VRRP-VRID_02` is the router's description.

Comment: sender and receiver are on two different subnets...

Comment: What is the subnet mask that is configured on both hosts?

Comment: @fvu I just type " ifconfig" in both host machine and both return “NetMask 255.255.0.0”. But this is the default subnet mask, right? I am not sure if the netmask which "ifconfig" returns is the actual subnet used in the local network. AND if not how to check the true subnet mask?  For instance, 10.180.23.140/25, will the "ifconfig" returns netmask of 255.255.255.0 OR 255.255.255.128?

Comment: @mtak I just type " ifconfig" in both host machine and both return “NetMask 255.255.0.0”. But this is the default subnet mask, right? I am not sure if the netmask which "ifconfig" returns is the actual subnet used in the local network. AND if not how to check the true subnet mask? For instance, 10.180.23.140/25, will the "ifconfig" returns netmask of 255.255.255.0 OR 255.255.255.128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosts are not directly connected to each other, they are connected to a router, which is serving as a gateway. 
When you have data to send, you first send it to your router with an IP address specified as the destination which the data must follow. 
Then, if the data is not destined for the same local network and an external one, the router checks its routing table and based on the entries in that table, it forwards the data out of an interface pointing to that network address. 
And if the data is destined for the same local network, it forwards it to the other host.

The data cannot directly travel between two hosts without interception from a router, unless you are in a local network. 
**Why does that happen?** Because when you have a network configured with a router, all hosts obtain a *default gateway route*, and they automatically send all data to where that route states. However, if this route is less-specific **or** absent, then the host would use its [ARP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) table to send the data directly to the other host (if in local network and directly connected).

**Note:** SSH is not a *direct* connection between two hosts. The router still forwards any data that is being sent through the SSH connection. A *direct* connection refers to a **direct** ***physical*** **connection**, thus the data is always being "guided" by a router.

**See also:**

**[Will packets send to the same subnet go through routers? @ superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/639941/will-packets-send-to-the-same-subnet-go-through-routers)**

**[A bit more in-depth guide on how routing works](https://cromwell-intl.com/networking/routing.html)**

**[OSI Model @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)**

Comment: You're somewhat mistaken about the routes a host has. The default route _does not_ have to be absent for direct ARP to happen; it only has to be less-specific than a direct subnet route. Nearly every host in practice will have a direct subnet route (based on the configured netmask), will use ARP to find hosts in the same subnet, and will use direct communication as far as the MAC layer is concerned. (Though of course OP's hosts probably aren't in the same subnet, so this won't apply.)

Comment: You're right about that it only has to be less-specific. I had forgotten about that part, thanks for reminding. I'll edit my post as to clear up the mistake and possible confusions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. So only the protocols lower than 3 layer can use the MAC address directly for transferring when a router present. But without a router, hosts should communicate directly whichever layer the protocol works on.

Comment: @forAllBright Unless in local network, as stated. If the two hosts are in the same network and the default gateway route is less-specific than the destination IP address for the same network, then the host will directly use ARP to communicate and send the data directly to the other host.

Comment: This doesn't even depend on the presence of a router. (By definition, the "default route" is the least specific route possible, i.e. `0.0.0.0/0` or `::/0`. So whether it's present or absent, the direct "local subnet" route will take priority anyway.) Even if you're talking about a combo home router, the packets will only travel as far as its L2 switch chip. (I'd consider that "direct" as it doesn't go through the L3 routing component.)